# MVC - sub-folders controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am thinking to create my own simple MVC framework in PHP. I thought it would be good idea to improve my skill in PHP.

I have a questions about admin section, how do you create it?

In kohana, controllers can be in sub-folders:

for example: `/controller/admin/admin.php`

What is other way? As long code can be shared to parent helpers/libs or parent models.

Comment: Your question is very broad. There are thousand and one other ways and it's not clear from your question what actual criteria would be.

Comment: Your question is very broad? That is your opinion.

Comment: Well, just share in *your* opinion what is specific about *your* question?

Answer (score 2):

First thing you have to notice is that Kohana is a HMVC framework. It is a bit different beast, compared to the rest of bunch. In this case `admin` is not so much a *module* as it is a namespace (though kohana is still using the PEAR-like "namespacing") for controllers and other classes.

This way additionally lets separate out other parts of application .. lets say you have a lot of code dealing with tagging and tag clouds. Then you can create another namespace/module just for that. And use them as sub-controllers. That's one of HMVC perks.

One other way of separating admin section from general application would be to treat them as separate applications, but then you need another location for shared components (most likely from *model layer*). Then you have more then one `/appliation/` folder on your server.

Or you can do combination of two.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that the reason you want to create yet another MVC framework is indeed to improve your PHP skills, and not to try to create a framework to use in a daily basis at your company, for example. I know that you didn't ask for such advice, but there are so many great MVC frameworks out there (and you probably know many of them already). I think it is a great approach to learn design patterns and increment your skills in PHP (or any other language), though.

As of your question, the most common approaches I have seen is to use different directories, like the "admin" subdirectory you mentioned, for then enforce name suffixes or prefixes for the controllers, like "UsersAdminController.php" e.g, adding "AdminController" at the end.

One thing that using a subdirectory may be better is that it enforces a better separation of concerns, and reduces the possibility of you ending with a lot of classes with simmilar in the same directory, which may cause confusion at some point.

Comment: Actually most of php frameworks are utter crap. Global state everywhere, derelict code fragments, obsession with ORMs, stunted authentication/authorization systems, ignorance of SOLID principles ..  you could say that making a framework is reinventing a wheel, but PHP community is still in process of making that wheel round.

Comment: @tereško I agree with that statement. PHP doesn't have what ruby has. We don't have a standard mature framework.

Comment: @Daniel , if with "mature framework" in ruby you mean the one, which the creators described as "framework for prototyping and should not be used for production code" and which actually has caused this retard-storm of ActiveRecord and caused mis-implementation of MVC in other in current web frameworks .. then you are clueless.

Comment: @tereško "mature framework" meaning something that is rock solid in it's standard and it's implementation. Many frameworks in php are dead-awful. Just a bunch of bloated tangled code. Frameworks don't necessary have to be an implementation of mvc or ActiveRecord. Though there are many ActiveRecord implementations in the recent mvc frameworks. Though the mis-implementation of mvc can be debatable.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating your own framework is a great idea, if only as an exercise to better understand the structure behind a web app.

I'm doing it so myself, and I think your approach depends very much on how far you want to go.

I started with a multilanguage support subsystem and user database management classes and now I'm moving to content management and database query sanitization.

I keep my classes separated in files and grouped by subsystems in folders, like multilang or admin, I think it's the best approach.